# How can i switch from one app to another in Django while passing data?

Tags: django, view, render, cart

I am writing a Django application and i got stuck at this line of code in html in one of my Django apps:

```
<a href="{% url "order:order_page" request.cart %} "> ORDER </a>
```

I want the word 'ORDER' to redirrect to a html page in another app while passing the data from 'cart'. How can i do that? (order is the second application, 'order_page' is the name in its view which renders the second html page and 'cart' is a data that i want to pass to it, because i want to display it)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Apps are not any kind of division in your site, they are just logical groupings of models and views.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what exactly isn't clear so i can explain better

Comment: What is not clear is why you think going from one app to another is a problem. It's not any different from going between two URLs in the same app.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am not saying it is a problem, but i do not know how to do that if i also have data to transfer from the first app to the other one.

Comment: As Daniel pointed out, it's not different than going to another url/view from within the same app.

Comment: I think you can only use absolute url becase that come from another app so that your application don't know how to reserve it using `url` tag. `<a href="//orderapp.com/path/card_id">ORDER</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the name of another app is `order`.

Then your `order.urls.py` should have:

```
from order import views
...
app_name = 'order'
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('order_page/<int:cart>/', views.OrderPage.as_view(), name='order_page'),    # OrderPage is a class based view
]
```

And you can point to this url in your template using:

```
<a href="{% url 'order:order_page' request.cart.id %}"> ORDER </a>
```

- `order:order_page`: the url named `order_page` in the app named `order`.
- `request.cart.id`: the parameter to pass to the url.
- Read [Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) for more details.

Comment: This is what i was asking, than you. Can you please explain what does that int:cart do and where does the 'int' come from? Thanks a lot

Comment: I have added more explanation. Please check!

Comment: unfortunately, my project still doesn't work. The error is : Reverse for 'order_page' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['order\\/order_page\\/(?P<cart>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Comment: Try using "/<int:cart>/" or "/(?P<cart>\d+)/" in the url instead of "/(?P<cart>[0-9]+)/".